# Post form data to another PHP page, Get the JSON and direct based on parsing the JSON

Tags: php

Ok So I have a basic login page with a form:

```
<form name="register" class="form-horizontal" id="signup" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" action="check.php">
                <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="text" class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">

                                <input id="name" name="name" type="name" placeholder="Enter your name"/> 

                    </div>
             </div>
                 <br>
             <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="passwd" class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">

                                <input id="pass" name="pass" type="pass" placeholder="Enter your password"/> 

                    </div>
                </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="left1">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
                     </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br> 


    </form>
```

On clicking submit I need to post the name and password to `check.php`. I do not want the browser to refresh the page to `check.php`.

It should get the resulting JSON array, parse it and based on that redirect if the login is successful.

Right now i can either post or get but not both. And I don't want the browser to refresh the page to `check.php`.

**UPDATE:**

I'm still not getting this to work. Have a look please.

```
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="login-form">
                <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="text" class="control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">

                                <input name="email" id="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="Enter your email"/> 

                    </div>
             </div>
                 <br>
             <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="passwd" class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">

                                <input name="passwd" id="passwd" type="password" value="" placeholder="Enter your password"/> 

                    </div>
                </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="left1">
                        <input type="button" id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-success"/>
                     </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <br>    
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>



$('#login').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"login.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: $("#login-form").serialize()
        }).done(function(data){
              alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
       });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try using the AJAX get/post.....

Comment: form page -> check.php -> redirect to success.php OR fail.php. You don't need ajax to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture all of the form's data and submit it to a PHP script - jQuery Ajax POST example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/capture-all-of-the-forms-data-and-submit-it-to-a-php-script-jquery-ajax-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS ONE
add jquery-1.9.1.js

```
       <form class="form-horizontal" id="login-form">
            <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="text" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="Enter your email"/> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group input-append">
                <label for="passwd" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input name="passwd" id="passwd" type="password" value="" placeholder="Enter your password"/> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="left1">
                        <input type="button" id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-success"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

<script>
$('#login').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"login.php",
        type:'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize()
    }).done(function(data){
        var json_text = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        obj = JSON.parse(json_text);
        if(obj.status == 'done') 
            alert('you are logged in'); 
    });
});
</script>
```

In the login page use like this

```
    <?php 
    $login = $_POST['email']; 
    $pass = $_POST['passwd'];
// LOGIN CHECKING 
    $data['status'] = 'done';
    echo json_encode($data);
    ?>
```

Comment: I want to post the data as form data itself, not as JSON how do I do this?

Comment: We have to use "dataType:'json'" to recieve as json array. "echo json_encode($data);" will create json array in php.

Comment: gimmie 5 mins to get back to you

Comment: I added <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> but nothing happens on clicking the button

Comment: how do I just print the JSON that I am getting from the other page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38105/discussion-between-eugine-joseph-and-paulie)

Answer (score 0):

Since you dont want the page to reload, i would go for ajax posting this to the php-script that handles the login.

```
<form id="login-form">
    <input type="text" name="user_name" value=""/>
    <input type="password" name="password" value=""/>
    <input type="button" id="login" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Then i would suggest you use jquery to make the ajax-handling easier. And it should look something like this:

```
  $('#login').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: PHP_PAGE_THAT_HANDLES_LOGIN.php,
        type:'POST',
        data: $("#login-form").serialize()
        }).done(function(data){
               /* Here you will recieve the data that 
               *  has been returned from the php page.
               *  so if its a success you can redirect 
               *  here with a window.location = "www.site.com/welcome.php";
               */
       });
    }
});
```

The attributes added in the ajax call under the param data will be recieved in the php page as $_POST["user_name"] and $_POST["password"]

Comment: how can I print the JSON that I am getting back? 
This does not seem to be working: alert(data);

Comment: You can print json data like this: alert(JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: do i need to include the jquery script to make this work? right now clicking the button is not working for me.